# Remove notification from android notification bar

Tags: android-notifications

I have created an application and with an Application class OnCreate event I manage to add notification in android notification bar. Now I need sample how to remove that notification from notification bar when the user stop the app from settings -> Application -> Running services

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your notification in the onDestroy() method of your activity by calling the cancelNotification() method from the `NotificationListenerService` class

Answer (score 0):

Please read this post here:

[Cancel notification on remove application from multitask panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel/14374761#14374761)

it is the same procedure as with a multitask-panel kill.