# How to remove all notifications when an android app (activity or service) is killed?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have an app with an activity and an intent service running in the background.

There's also a notification which shows a progress bar with the progress of the background process (it's downloading a lot of files from a server).

The activity shows the download progress ( user can't meaningfully use the app before these assets are downloaded). When this activity is closed, the notification with the progress bar is shown.

My issue: When the application is killed via the "task manager" (accessible via right button on android 4.0, the one with the two rectangles), the notification is still there. But it's basically a zombie, because the service that used to update it is dead.

Put in a different way: How can I remove a (or all) notification(s) when my application is killed?

Comment: you can check if `onDestroy` is called in the service

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately onDestroy is not called when the app is killed.

Comment: I assume the notification's intent is the main activity?

Comment: Yes, you can assume so. When the notification is clicked, the activity is started.

Comment: Then I would say that the notification remains relatively relevant. (except it gives the false notion that the download is still running.)

Comment: Yes, the problem is that there's a progress bar, but no progress is happening anymore. And since I wasn't able to remove or update this notification, this would give the user the wrong impression.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@See
[public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29).
This is called if the service is currently running and the user has removed a task that comes from the service's application. If you have set `ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK` flag then you will not receive this callback; instead, the service will simply be stopped.

You can remove all notifications that your app has created with [`cancelAll()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll()):

```
NotificationManager nManager = ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
nManager.cancelAll();
```

According to the API docs, this will

> Cancel all previously shown notifications.

in the same way that [`cancel(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) does:

> Cancel a previously shown notification. If it's transient, the view will be hidden. If it's persistent, it will be removed from the status bar.

Comment: the question is not how to remove notification. the question is how to detect an application is killed by the system (so that he can remove the notification).

Comment: This will no longer work on API level >=26 because of background services limitation - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services This solution is no longer viable, this service will be stopped by the system after a while (so it can miss onTaskRemoved event)

Comment: For some devices onTaskRemoved will never be called until user enables the setting like Settings > permissions > Autostart. Please be cautious to handle any usecase within this method. For more details please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660216/ontaskremoved-not-getting-called-in-huawei-and-xiomi-devices

Answer (score 4):

It seems that

[onTaskRemoved](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29)

of the Service DOES get called when the user kills the application task (by swiping out the app in the "task manager". I am able to remove the Notification from here.

Comment: Does not work for API level >= 26, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47110577/1000551

Answer (score 0):

You can not track if application is killed from Activity or Application class.

I found a solution for this in the following link :
[Cancel notification on remove application from multitask panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel)

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

use in your notification builder the `setTimeoutAfter` and then use a recursive call that starts a coroutine to refresh the notification before it cancels itself.

This way, if your service is killed (which won't go through onDestroy or receive any other callbacks to trigger cancellation of the notification) the notification simply times out for you. And the only way a service that is started + bound will be stopped is when the OS kills the application after being idle.

*not* using a foreground service also means that your normal application lifecycle won't be inhibited. It's tricky to get right, but doable.

see methods `buildNotification` and `notify`, and `launchRefreshNotificationJob` from https://github.com/05nelsonm/TorOnionProxyLibrary-Android/blob/master/topl-service/src/main/java/io/matthewnelson/topl_service/notification/ServiceNotification.kt

Answer (score 0):

you can write the code to remove the notification in this callback method of the service class. and if else condition clear rest of the thing.

```
 override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        stopForeground(true)
    }else{
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager .cancelAll() 
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Did you tried [onStop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) ? It worked for me. I called cancelAll() in onStop. It closes all notification on removal of app from task Manager.

Note : But it also remove all notification when your app goes in background. In that case you can re invoke those notification using  background process.

```
@Override public void onStop (){
    super.onStop();
    cancelAllNotification(getApplicationContext());
}

public static void cancelAllNotification(Context ctx) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.cancelAll();
}
```

Comment: No this won't work since the application is actually stopped. The notification is visible while the app is in the background.