# How to use Android L UsageStatsManager?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, usage-statistics

I'm trying to get the application usage list in android lollipop using UsageStatsManager, for that I have gone through the android developer document https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html
I don't know how to use UsageStasManger, so I referred few links [How to get list of recent apps with Android API 21 Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284205/how-to-get-list-of-recent-apps-with-android-api-21-lollipop)
[Android Lollipop know if app as Usage Stats access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330339/android-lollipop-know-if-app-as-usage-stats-access)
and implement in my project but I didn't get any data from UsageStausManager? how do I Use UsageStausManager in my project. Anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

From lollipop we will not be able to use the activity manager for determining the current foreground tasks. we have to make use of the Usage Stats Manager. Wrote a small code and answered in this thread

[Determining the current foreground application from a background task or service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)

You can have a look at this thread by me.