# Checking if an application is running in foreground

Tags: android, service, process, permissions

In one of my application, I need to launch manually an application thanks to an `Intent` (which is not mine). After that, I want to know if this application launched by an `Intent` is running in foreground, in background or killed.

I founded a lot of example and snippets showing how to get the list of running processes/applications but they are calling methods whose are now deprecated since API 21 like `ActivityManager.RunningTasks(..)` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html).

The others methods like `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo` only return my current application and not all the other. I understand that this is a security issue of the access to personal information, but is there no other way ?

**EDIT 1**

After looking at the Android API, I found the class `UsageStatsManager` and judging by the following post, it seems to be an alternative : [How to get list of recent apps with Android API 21 Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284205/how-to-get-list-of-recent-apps-with-android-api-21-lollipop). I tried using `UsageStatsManager` but the result isn't satisfying. I've got a service which aim to regularly verify if the selected application is in foreground.

```
public class CastService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "CastService";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        ResolveInfo launchable = (ResolveInfo)intent.getExtras().get("selectedApp");
        final String packageName = launchable.activityInfo.packageName;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 2000; // ms

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "isAppInactive(" + packageName + ") : " + isAppInactive(packageName));
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isAppInactive(String packageName)
    {
        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        return usageStatsManager.isAppInactive(packageName);
    }
}
```

The service is working fine and log every two seconds the result of the method `isAppInactive`. Unfortunatetly, even if the concerned application is in background or killed, the result doesn't changed :

`I/CastService: isAppInactive(com.sec.android.gallery3d) : false`

I thought I forget to add the permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` but it doesn't fix it.

`<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>`

**EDIT 2**

Looking at another example (), I rewrote my `isAppForeground` function but still not working. My list of `UsageStats` is always empty.

```
protected boolean isAppForeground(String packageName)
{
    UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<UsageStats> stats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 10, time);

    String topPackageName = new String();

    if(stats != null)
    {
        SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();

        for (UsageStats usageStats : stats)
        {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);
        }

        if(mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty())
        {
            topPackageName =  mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
        }
    }

    return topPackageName.equals(packageName);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my application settings, there was no trace of permission, so I decided to check if the permission `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` was really granted thanks to the following function.

```
public static boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context, String permission)
{
    AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
    int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(permission, android.os.Process.myUid(), context.getPackageName());
    boolean granted = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;

    Log.i(TAG, "isPermissionGranted(" + permission + ", " + android.os.Process.myUid() + ", " + context.getPackageName() + ") : " + granted);

    return granted;
}
```

I was testing my application in debug mode and it didn't ask me to allow the previous permission. Thanks to the terminal and adb command line, I granted the permission manually and my function `isAppForeground` defined in previous EDIT is finally working fine.

`adb -d shell pm grant com.package.name android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`