# startActivity(intent): Is there any way to know if the application will be resumed or restarted?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using `startActivity(intent)` to start an application. I need to know whether the application will be resumed form background or will it be restarted (i.e. it is not in background), before launching the application.

Before Lollipop, I used to get the list of recent tasks and check if it has an application with matching package name.
But in Lollipop I cannot use `getRecentTask`, so this won't help.

Just for trial, I have also tried:

```
originalIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

if(originalIntent != null){
    mainActivityIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    mainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    if(originalIntent.equals(mainActivityIntent))
        Log.d("temp", "New Task");
    else
        Log.d("temp", "Background Task");
}
```

without any success.

What can be done?

Note: The other application I am switching to can be any other application installed on the phone and not necessary my application.

Comment: Is the second app your own application?
You can in second app send intent, and receive it in first app using broadcast receiver.

Comment: @Unmerciful No I isn't, it can be any other application

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590533/how-to-get-recent-tasks-on-android-l

Answer (score 1):

Use onRestart and onResume method

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When is restarted activity (not in exec) always execute onCreate, when come from background not.

In onCreate method set a variable:

```
isNewLaunch = true;
```

And check it in onResume:

```
if(isNewLaunch) {

} else {

}
```

Set a false in onPause or onStop

```
isNewLaunch = false;
```