# Is there a function to get a list of the recently used apps in android? Update for Pie

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, android-recents

I have searched for days on a way to do this but none of them really suite my needs or I have a hard time understanding them. I am looking to get all of the apps that would normally show up on the recent screen. All of the questions that have been asked on this question are like 5  years old so I am looking for an up to date answer.

If this is impossible, is there a way to open the recent apps dialogue programmatically?

This was a pretty good answer but I'm not really sure how to use it so it isn't getting the apps from just 10 seconds ago
[How to get recent tasks on Android "L"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590533/how-to-get-recent-tasks-on-android-l)