# Android - switch to last opened external app activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-package-managers

I'm looking for a method to switch to the previously opened external app activity. I'm developing an app with a background service.

there are many apps that has this function already as [this one (LAS)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abhi.lastappswitcher&hl=es)

`getRecentTasks()` is deprecated

I found also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590533/how-to-get-recent-tasks-on-android-l)
however it returns the package, which when I try to launch opens the app from the start, not from the last opened activity. How can I do this?

Comment: There's really no way to do this.  ANd if you launch it as an activity, you could be screwing things up (you're unlikely to have the same intent parameters).  The best/only way to do this is to finish() all of your activites.  Then the last activity before your app will be on top.

Comment: Thanks but I'm asking about dealing with EXTERNAL apps through my service. NOT MY APP activities.