# which method is called in android on Recent App Button

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-recents, recent-screens

In my application I need to call a method as Recent App Button is pressed,
I am developing an application in which I need to change a value on Firebase on Recent App Button Pressed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get recent tasks on Android "L"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590533/how-to-get-recent-tasks-on-android-l)

Comment: No,
I need some method or a listener which is called on pressing Recent App button.

Comment: There is no event specific to that operation. At most, there will be activity lifecycle events (e.g., `onPause()`, `onStop()`), as there are with other forms of navigation.