# Android how to detect apps running in split screen mode

Tags: android, kotlin, usagestatsmanager, split-screen

The top solution for this post: [How to get recent tasks on Android "L"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24590533/how-to-get-recent-tasks-on-android-l/26885469#26885469) is about getting which app is running in the foreground.

The method shows how to query all usage stats, and then read the top-most entry to know which app is running in the foreground. But it could only detect single apps. Once the app goes split-screen, it can no longer be detected.

I would like to ask for a solution that could detect all foreground apps running, using real-time queries.

A sidenote: When I try to use the UsageEvents.Event approach to obtain the live states of these packages (denoted by the enums ACTIVITY_PAUSED and ACTIVITY_RESUMED) it did not work for me because the states are completely wrong. I suspect that this is a bug on Android's side. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event