# close notification on remove app from list by swip

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app that play some media and media can be played or paused from notification bar.now I want to close notification when user remove app from his phone's app list by swiping.I know that the activity `onDestroy()` method does not call.

here is some part of my code:

```
public class MyNotification extends Notification {

    private Context ctx;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    RemoteViews mContentView;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public MyNotification(Context ctx) {
        super();
        this.ctx = ctx;
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
        CharSequence tickerText = G.lastPlayingBookMaster.getName();
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Notification notification = this;
        notification.when = when;
        notification.tickerText = tickerText;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            notification.icon = R.drawable.icon_notification_white;
        }else{
            notification.icon = R.drawable.icon_launcher;
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(548853, notification);
    }
}
```

And in my main activity I have this method:

```
 public void showNotification() {
    myNotification = new MyNotification(this);
}
```

Now what can I do????
tnx

Comment: Try with onStop() method of activity to remove notification using mNotificationManager.cancel(548853);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel notification on remove application from multitask panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel)

Comment: I saw that and I tried to do but it did not work for me