# Android Notification doesn't work after NotificationManager.cancel()

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I have a service1 broadcasts the service status to MainActivity, MainActivity sends a notification after receive the broadcast. This notification is flagged as a non cancelable notification. In order to cancel the notification when the app is killed from the task panel, I binded the activity with KillNotificationsService which is provided in [Cancel notification on remove application from multitask panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel)
 for the solution to cancel notification. 
I also need to cancel the notification when service1 stops. So I put

```
   @Override
public void onDestroy(Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(KillNotificationsService.NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

(NOTIFICATION ID is a static variable in KillNotificationsService).

After I canceled this notification, the next time I start service1, after service1 broadcasts the status, the notification with same id(NOTIFICATION_ID) won't appear. I tried to assign unique Ids and gc for the notification, but it didn't seem working.

If anyone can help me.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what you are trying to do and what is not working

Comment: I have edited the post, English is not my first language, let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Share the broadcast receiver used to display notification. Also the the broadcast sent from service. The code you shared seems ok.

Comment: Yes, sharing the broadcast receiver is not only used to display notification, there are more UI works. Before that, I put notification inside server1, the notification will be canceled itself when I stop the service. However if I kill the app without stopping service, the notification will always be there. So I found the solution of KillNotificationsService. It is not possible to bind one service to another, so I pulled the notification out of the service.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using context of broadcast receiver to build notification

use application context to build notification.

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
NotificationManager mNotificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
mNotificationManager.notify(KillNotificationsService.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```