# Remove notification icon of killed foreground service (Android)

Tags: android, android-notifications, foreground-service

After I killed the application (incl. foreground service) through the app settings, then the notification icon that is bind to the foreground service remains visible.

Is it possible to remove the icon after the application was killed?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem is a little bit different but similar and I found the solution with the answers in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel) I found a solution (thx @Anubhav Gupta).

You can override the `onTaskRemoved` function in which the foreground service can be stopped.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    context.stopService(intent);
}
```