# How to reference an Edit Text value from Activity class to Non-Activity class

Tags: java, android

i need to get the value in editTextText from ShowURL class to use in Recorder class to set the IP address for okHttp request

the ShowURL class is like this:

```
package fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Map;

import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.R;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.control.LogsManager;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.control.PreferencesManager;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.control.Recorder;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.control.SensorsManager;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.log.CalibrationLog;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.log.Log;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.sensors.Sensor;

public class ShowURL extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LogsManager mLogsManager;
    private PreferencesManager mPreferencesManager;
    private Log mLog;
    EditText MyURL;
    public static String IP;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.url);
        MyURL = findViewById(R.id.editTextText);

    }

    public void Click (View view) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String URL = MyURL.getText().toString();

        Recorder yourObject = new Recorder(this, mLogsManager, mPreferencesManager);
        yourObject.setIp(URL);
        yourObject.getIp();
        android.util.Log.d("IP Value", "IP: " + yourObject.getIp());
    }
}
```

and the targeted class to get the value of EditText is:

```
package fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.control;


import static android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice.getDeviceId;
import static androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.SensorPrivacyManager;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Pair;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.sensors.AndroidSensor;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.ui.LogsActivity;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.ui.MainActivity;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.ui.ShowURL;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.Application;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.R;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.FieldsWritableObject;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.PositionReference;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.log.CalibrationLog;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.log.Log;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.sensors.CameraRecorder;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.model.sensors.Sensor;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.ui.RecordActivity;
import fr.inria.tyrex.senslogs.ui.utils.KillNotificationsService;

/**
 * Handle timers and record sensors data
 */
public class Recorder {

    public final static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private final Context mContext;

    private static final String TAG = "DeviceID";
    private final LogsManager mLogsManager;
    private final PreferencesManager mPreferencesManager;

    private RecorderWriter mRecorderWriter;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Log mLog;

    private Map<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> mSensorsAndSettings;
    private LinkedList<PositionReference> mReferences;


    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private boolean isInitialized = false;

    private Float f, f2 = null;
    private  Float initialAltitude = null;
    private Bundle mExtraData; // Declare mExtraData variable

    private String mIP = getIp();

    public String getIp() {
        return mIP;
    }
    public String setIp(String ip) {
        mIP = ip;
        return mIP;
    }

    public Recorder(Context context, LogsManager logsManager,
                    PreferencesManager preferencesManager) {
        mContext = context;
        mLogsManager = logsManager;
        mPreferencesManager = preferencesManager;
        mReferences = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public boolean isRecording() {
        return isRecording;
    }

    public boolean isRecording(Sensor sensor) {
        return mSensorsAndSettings.containsKey(sensor);
    }

    private void init(@NonNull Map<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorsAndSettings,
                      @Nullable CalibrationLog.Type calibration)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Store sensors and their settings
        mSensorsAndSettings = sensorsAndSettings;

        mLog = calibration != null ?
                CalibrationLog.create(calibration, mSensorsAndSettings.keySet()) :
                new Log(mSensorsAndSettings.keySet());

        mLog.init(mContext);
        mReferences.clear();

        // We need to create a new instance because writer is used during zip creation task
        mRecorderWriter = new RecorderWriter(mContext);
        mRecorderWriter.init(mLog);
    }

    public void play() throws FileNotFoundException {
        play(mPreferencesManager.getSelectedSensors(), null);
    }

    public void play(Map<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorsAndSettings, CalibrationLog.Type calibration)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        if (isRecording) return;


        // Need to init some properties for the first play
        if (!isInitialized) {
            init(sensorsAndSettings, calibration);
            isInitialized = true;
        }


        // Start and listen sensors
        for (final Map.Entry<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorAndSetting : mSensorsAndSettings.entrySet()) {

            final Sensor sensor = sensorAndSetting.getKey();
            final Sensor.Settings settings = sensorAndSetting.getValue();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && sensor instanceof CameraRecorder) {
                mRecorderWriter.updateVideoPath();
            }

            if (sensor instanceof FieldsWritableObject) {
                sensor.setListener(new Sensor.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNewValues(double diffTimeSystem, double diffTimeSensor, Object[] objects) {

                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                        Map<String, Object> data = getMapValue(sensor.getType(), objects);

                        // Define the request body
                        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        String json = new Gson().toJson(data); // JSON payload
                        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);
                        String IP = setIp(mIP);
                        android.util.Log.d("CEK ISI", "Isi mIP: " + IP);
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url("http://theAddress")
                                .post(requestBody)
                                .build();

                        // Send the request asynchronously
                        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                // Handle the response
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Request successful
                                    final String responseBody = response.body().string();

                                } else {
                                    // Request unsuccessful
                                    // Handle error case
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                                // Handle network failure
                            }
                        });

                        String Tag = new String();
                        String Data = new String();
                        String ID = new String();
                        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        android.util.Log.d(Data, "Value :" + new Gson().toJson(objects));
                        android.util.Log.d("VALUE SENSOR TIPE", String.valueOf(sensor.getType()));
                        android.util.Log.d("VALUE SENSOR", String.valueOf(objects));
                        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        android.util.Log.d(Tag, "Device ID: " + androidId);
                        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        sdf.format(date);
                        // Convert timestamp to a human-readable date and time format
                        String formattedTime = String.valueOf(date);
                        android.util.Log.d("Timestamp", "Current timestamp: " + timestamp);
                        android.util.Log.d("Timestamp", "Formatted time: " + formattedTime);
                        mRecorderWriter.asycWrite(sensor, diffTimeSystem, diffTimeSensor, objects);
                        android.util.Log.d("Time Sys: ","Time System: " + diffTimeSystem);
                        android.util.Log.d("Time Sen: ","Time Sensor: " + diffTimeSensor);

                    }
                });
            }

            // Some sensors take a long time to start but have to be run on UI thread
            if (sensor.mustRunOnUiThread()) {
                sensor.start(mContext, settings, mLog.getRecordTimes());
            } else {
                new Thread(() -> sensor.start(mContext, settings, mLog.getRecordTimes())).start();
            }
        }

        createNotification();
        startTimer();
        isRecording = true;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getMapValue(int type, Object[] objects) {
        Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.format(date);
        // Convert timestamp to a human-readable date and time format
        String formattedTime = String.valueOf(date);

//        final Map.Entry<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorAndSetting = null;
//        final Sensor sensor = sensorAndSetting.getKey();
//        final Sensor.Settings settings = sensorAndSetting.getValue();

//        String CT = toString();
//        String FT = new String();


        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("accel x", objects[0]);
                value.put("accel y", objects[1]);
                value.put("accel z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 35:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
//                value.put("Time Sensor", CT);
//                value.put("Time System", FT);
                value.put("uncal accel x", objects[0]);
                value.put("uncal accel y", objects[1]);
                value.put("uncal accel z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 2:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("magneto x", objects[0]);
                value.put("magneto y", objects[1]);
                value.put("magneto z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 14:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("uncal magneto x", objects[0]);
                value.put("uncal magneto y", objects[1]);
                value.put("uncal magneto z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("gyro x", objects[0]);
                value.put("gyro y", objects[1]);
                value.put("gyro z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 16:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("uncal gyro x", objects[0]);
                value.put("uncal gyro y", objects[1]);
                value.put("uncal gyro z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                float[] fArr = new float[4];
                float[] fArr2 = new float[9];
                float[] fArr3 = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(fArr, (float[]) objects[0]);
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(fArr2, (float[]) objects[0]);
                SensorManager.getOrientation(fArr2, fArr3);
                value.put("yaw", fArr3[0]);
                value.put("pitch", fArr3[1]);
                value.put("roll", fArr3[2]);
                value.put("qw", fArr[0]);
                value.put("qx", fArr[1]);
                value.put("qy", fArr[2]);
                value.put("qz", fArr[3]);
                break;
            case 5:
                value.put("lux", objects[0]);
                break;
            case 768:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("GPS Latitude", objects[0]);
                value.put("GPS Longitude", objects[1]);
                value.put("GPS Altitude", objects[2]);
                value.put("GPS Bearing", objects[3]);
                value.put("GPS Accuracy", objects[4]);
                value.put("GPS Speed", objects[5]);
                break;
            case 6:
                float altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(1013.25f, (Float) objects[0]);
                if (f == null) {
                    initialAltitude = Float.valueOf(altitude);
                }
                f2 = initialAltitude;
                float floatValue = f2 == null ? altitude : f2.floatValue();
                value.put("pressure", objects[0]);
                value.put("relativeAltitude", altitude - floatValue);
                break;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public void pause() {

        if (!isRecording) return;

        stopTimer();
        removeNotification();

        for (final Sensor sensor : mSensorsAndSettings.keySet()) {

            sensor.setListener(null);

            if (sensor.mustRunOnUiThread()) {
                sensor.stop(mContext);
            } else {
                new Thread(() -> sensor.stop(mContext)).start();
            }
        }

        mLog.getRecordTimes().endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1e3d;
        isRecording = false;
    }


    public void cancel() throws IOException {

        if (isRecording) {
            pause();
        }
        resetTimer();
        mRecorderWriter.finish();
        mRecorderWriter.removeFiles();
        isInitialized = false;
        isRecording = false;
    }


    public Log save(String title) throws IOException {
        return save(title, null, null, null);
    }

    public Log save(String title, String user, String positionOrientation, String comment) throws IOException {

        mRecorderWriter.writeReferences(mReferences);
        mRecorderWriter.finish();

        resetTimer();

        // Set title to unknown if null and replace non word characters by underscore
        if (title == null || title.isEmpty()) {
            title = mContext.getString(R.string.record_finished_empty_filename);
        }
        String filename = title.replaceAll("\\W+", "_");

        mLog.setName(title);
        mLog.setUser(user);
        mLog.setComment(comment);
        mLog.setPositionOrientation(positionOrientation);
        mLog.setUncompressedSize(mRecorderWriter.getDataSize());


        // Create Zip File
        final Pair<File, ZipCreationTask> zipCreationPair = mRecorderWriter.createZipFile(filename, mLog);
        final File zipFile = zipCreationPair.first;
        final ZipCreationTask zipTask = zipCreationPair.second;

        mLog.setZipCreationTask(zipTask);

        zipTask.addListener(new ZipCreationTask.ZipCreationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(File currentFile, float ratio) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskFinished(File outputFile, long fileSize) {
                // Remove files when recorder finished
                mRecorderWriter.removeFiles();
                zipTask.removeListener(this);
            }
        });

        mLog.setZipFile(zipFile);

        mLogsManager.addLog(mLog);

        isInitialized = false;

        return mLog;
    }


    public Log.RecordTimes getRecordTimes() {
        return mLog.getRecordTimes();
    }


    public void addReference(double latitude, double longitude, Float level) {
        double elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1e3d - mLog.getRecordTimes().startTime;
        mReferences.add(new PositionReference(elapsedTime, latitude, longitude, level));
    }

    public void removeLastReference() {
        mReferences.pollLast();
    }


    //<editor-fold desc="DataSize">
    public long getDataSize() {
        return mRecorderWriter.getDataSize();
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    //<editor-fold desc="Timer">
    private long firstTime;
    private long computeTime;

    public long getCurrentTime() {
        return computeTime + System.currentTimeMillis() - firstTime;
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        computeTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - firstTime;
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        computeTime = 0;
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    //<editor-fold desc="Notification">

    private void createNotification() {
        mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext, KillNotificationsService.class),
                mNotificationConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private void removeNotification() {
        mContext.unbindService(mNotificationConnection);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }


    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel
    private ServiceConnection mNotificationConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder binder) {
            ((KillNotificationsService.KillBinder) binder).service.startService(
                    new Intent(mContext, KillNotificationsService.class));

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RecordActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                            .setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setContentText(mContext.getString(R.string.record_notification))
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        }

    };
    //</editor-fold>


}
```

i need to use the editTextText value to set the IP address in the Recorder class to proceed okHttp request, the code above show no error but when i check logcat to see the value of mIP it show that is null

Comment: is the value of URL null?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a public static variable in your ShowURL class which contains the value of the EditText. Example code:

```
public class ShowURL extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String edittext_value; //Create a variable 
    private LogsManager mLogsManager;
    private PreferencesManager mPreferencesManager;
    private Log mLog;
    EditText MyURL;
    public static String IP;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.url);
        MyURL = findViewById(R.id.editTextText);
        //Assign the variable 
        edittext_value = MyUrl.getText().toString();
    }

     …
```

Then you can access the variable in your Recorder class like below:

```
String example_var = ShowURL.edittext_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your getter and setter for `mIP`. The following code is causing the value always be null.

```
//incorrect way
private String mIP = getIp();

public String getIp() {
    return mIP;
}
public String setIp(String ip) {
    mIP = ip;
    return mIP;
}
```

This should be changed like this:

```
//The correct method
private String mIP;

public String getIp() {
    return mIP;
}
public void setIp(String ip) {
    mIP = ip;
}
```

Then use the `mIP` variable within the `Recorder` class or `getIp()` method to read the IP value outside the `Recorder` class.

Here is your final `Recorder` class

```
public class Recorder {

    public final static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private final Context mContext;

    private static final String TAG = "DeviceID";
    private final LogsManager mLogsManager;
    private final PreferencesManager mPreferencesManager;

    private RecorderWriter mRecorderWriter;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Log mLog;

    private Map<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> mSensorsAndSettings;
    private LinkedList<PositionReference> mReferences;


    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private boolean isInitialized = false;

    private Float f, f2 = null;
    private  Float initialAltitude = null;
    private Bundle mExtraData; // Declare mExtraData variable

    private String mIP;

    public String getIp() {
        return mIP;
    }
    public void setIp(String ip) {
        mIP = ip;
    }

    public Recorder(Context context, LogsManager logsManager,
                    PreferencesManager preferencesManager) {
        mContext = context;
        mLogsManager = logsManager;
        mPreferencesManager = preferencesManager;
        mReferences = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public boolean isRecording() {
        return isRecording;
    }

    public boolean isRecording(Sensor sensor) {
        return mSensorsAndSettings.containsKey(sensor);
    }

    private void init(@NonNull Map<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorsAndSettings,
                      @Nullable CalibrationLog.Type calibration)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Store sensors and their settings
        mSensorsAndSettings = sensorsAndSettings;

        mLog = calibration != null ?
                CalibrationLog.create(calibration, mSensorsAndSettings.keySet()) :
                new Log(mSensorsAndSettings.keySet());

        mLog.init(mContext);
        mReferences.clear();

        // We need to create a new instance because writer is used during zip creation task
        mRecorderWriter = new RecorderWriter(mContext);
        mRecorderWriter.init(mLog);
    }

    public void play() throws FileNotFoundException {
        play(mPreferencesManager.getSelectedSensors(), null);
    }

    public void play(Map<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorsAndSettings, CalibrationLog.Type calibration)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        if (isRecording) return;


        // Need to init some properties for the first play
        if (!isInitialized) {
            init(sensorsAndSettings, calibration);
            isInitialized = true;
        }


        // Start and listen sensors
        for (final Map.Entry<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorAndSetting : mSensorsAndSettings.entrySet()) {

            final Sensor sensor = sensorAndSetting.getKey();
            final Sensor.Settings settings = sensorAndSetting.getValue();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && sensor instanceof CameraRecorder) {
                mRecorderWriter.updateVideoPath();
            }

            if (sensor instanceof FieldsWritableObject) {
                sensor.setListener(new Sensor.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNewValues(double diffTimeSystem, double diffTimeSensor, Object[] objects) {

                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                        Map<String, Object> data = getMapValue(sensor.getType(), objects);

                        // Define the request body
                        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        String json = new Gson().toJson(data); // JSON payload
                        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);
                        String IP = mIP;
                        android.util.Log.d("CEK ISI", "Isi mIP: " + IP);
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url("http://theAddress")
                                .post(requestBody)
                                .build();

                        // Send the request asynchronously
                        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                // Handle the response
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Request successful
                                    final String responseBody = response.body().string();

                                } else {
                                    // Request unsuccessful
                                    // Handle error case
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                                // Handle network failure
                            }
                        });

                        String Tag = new String();
                        String Data = new String();
                        String ID = new String();
                        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        android.util.Log.d(Data, "Value :" + new Gson().toJson(objects));
                        android.util.Log.d("VALUE SENSOR TIPE", String.valueOf(sensor.getType()));
                        android.util.Log.d("VALUE SENSOR", String.valueOf(objects));
                        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        android.util.Log.d(Tag, "Device ID: " + androidId);
                        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        sdf.format(date);
                        // Convert timestamp to a human-readable date and time format
                        String formattedTime = String.valueOf(date);
                        android.util.Log.d("Timestamp", "Current timestamp: " + timestamp);
                        android.util.Log.d("Timestamp", "Formatted time: " + formattedTime);
                        mRecorderWriter.asycWrite(sensor, diffTimeSystem, diffTimeSensor, objects);
                        android.util.Log.d("Time Sys: ","Time System: " + diffTimeSystem);
                        android.util.Log.d("Time Sen: ","Time Sensor: " + diffTimeSensor);

                    }
                });
            }

            // Some sensors take a long time to start but have to be run on UI thread
            if (sensor.mustRunOnUiThread()) {
                sensor.start(mContext, settings, mLog.getRecordTimes());
            } else {
                new Thread(() -> sensor.start(mContext, settings, mLog.getRecordTimes())).start();
            }
        }

        createNotification();
        startTimer();
        isRecording = true;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getMapValue(int type, Object[] objects) {
        Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
        String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.format(date);
        // Convert timestamp to a human-readable date and time format
        String formattedTime = String.valueOf(date);

//        final Map.Entry<Sensor, Sensor.Settings> sensorAndSetting = null;
//        final Sensor sensor = sensorAndSetting.getKey();
//        final Sensor.Settings settings = sensorAndSetting.getValue();

//        String CT = toString();
//        String FT = new String();


        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("accel x", objects[0]);
                value.put("accel y", objects[1]);
                value.put("accel z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 35:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
//                value.put("Time Sensor", CT);
//                value.put("Time System", FT);
                value.put("uncal accel x", objects[0]);
                value.put("uncal accel y", objects[1]);
                value.put("uncal accel z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 2:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("magneto x", objects[0]);
                value.put("magneto y", objects[1]);
                value.put("magneto z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 14:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("uncal magneto x", objects[0]);
                value.put("uncal magneto y", objects[1]);
                value.put("uncal magneto z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("gyro x", objects[0]);
                value.put("gyro y", objects[1]);
                value.put("gyro z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 16:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("uncal gyro x", objects[0]);
                value.put("uncal gyro y", objects[1]);
                value.put("uncal gyro z", objects[2]);
                break;
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                float[] fArr = new float[4];
                float[] fArr2 = new float[9];
                float[] fArr3 = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(fArr, (float[]) objects[0]);
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(fArr2, (float[]) objects[0]);
                SensorManager.getOrientation(fArr2, fArr3);
                value.put("yaw", fArr3[0]);
                value.put("pitch", fArr3[1]);
                value.put("roll", fArr3[2]);
                value.put("qw", fArr[0]);
                value.put("qx", fArr[1]);
                value.put("qy", fArr[2]);
                value.put("qz", fArr[3]);
                break;
            case 5:
                value.put("lux", objects[0]);
                break;
            case 768:
                value.put("Device ID", androidId);
                value.put("Current Timestamp", timestamp);
                value.put("Formatted Timestamp", formattedTime);
                value.put("GPS Latitude", objects[0]);
                value.put("GPS Longitude", objects[1]);
                value.put("GPS Altitude", objects[2]);
                value.put("GPS Bearing", objects[3]);
                value.put("GPS Accuracy", objects[4]);
                value.put("GPS Speed", objects[5]);
                break;
            case 6:
                float altitude = SensorManager.getAltitude(1013.25f, (Float) objects[0]);
                if (f == null) {
                    initialAltitude = Float.valueOf(altitude);
                }
                f2 = initialAltitude;
                float floatValue = f2 == null ? altitude : f2.floatValue();
                value.put("pressure", objects[0]);
                value.put("relativeAltitude", altitude - floatValue);
                break;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public void pause() {

        if (!isRecording) return;

        stopTimer();
        removeNotification();

        for (final Sensor sensor : mSensorsAndSettings.keySet()) {

            sensor.setListener(null);

            if (sensor.mustRunOnUiThread()) {
                sensor.stop(mContext);
            } else {
                new Thread(() -> sensor.stop(mContext)).start();
            }
        }

        mLog.getRecordTimes().endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1e3d;
        isRecording = false;
    }


    public void cancel() throws IOException {

        if (isRecording) {
            pause();
        }
        resetTimer();
        mRecorderWriter.finish();
        mRecorderWriter.removeFiles();
        isInitialized = false;
        isRecording = false;
    }


    public Log save(String title) throws IOException {
        return save(title, null, null, null);
    }

    public Log save(String title, String user, String positionOrientation, String comment) throws IOException {

        mRecorderWriter.writeReferences(mReferences);
        mRecorderWriter.finish();

        resetTimer();

        // Set title to unknown if null and replace non word characters by underscore
        if (title == null || title.isEmpty()) {
            title = mContext.getString(R.string.record_finished_empty_filename);
        }
        String filename = title.replaceAll("\\W+", "_");

        mLog.setName(title);
        mLog.setUser(user);
        mLog.setComment(comment);
        mLog.setPositionOrientation(positionOrientation);
        mLog.setUncompressedSize(mRecorderWriter.getDataSize());


        // Create Zip File
        final Pair<File, ZipCreationTask> zipCreationPair = mRecorderWriter.createZipFile(filename, mLog);
        final File zipFile = zipCreationPair.first;
        final ZipCreationTask zipTask = zipCreationPair.second;

        mLog.setZipCreationTask(zipTask);

        zipTask.addListener(new ZipCreationTask.ZipCreationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(File currentFile, float ratio) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskFinished(File outputFile, long fileSize) {
                // Remove files when recorder finished
                mRecorderWriter.removeFiles();
                zipTask.removeListener(this);
            }
        });

        mLog.setZipFile(zipFile);

        mLogsManager.addLog(mLog);

        isInitialized = false;

        return mLog;
    }


    public Log.RecordTimes getRecordTimes() {
        return mLog.getRecordTimes();
    }


    public void addReference(double latitude, double longitude, Float level) {
        double elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1e3d - mLog.getRecordTimes().startTime;
        mReferences.add(new PositionReference(elapsedTime, latitude, longitude, level));
    }

    public void removeLastReference() {
        mReferences.pollLast();
    }


    //<editor-fold desc="DataSize">
    public long getDataSize() {
        return mRecorderWriter.getDataSize();
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    //<editor-fold desc="Timer">
    private long firstTime;
    private long computeTime;

    public long getCurrentTime() {
        return computeTime + System.currentTimeMillis() - firstTime;
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        computeTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - firstTime;
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        computeTime = 0;
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    //<editor-fold desc="Notification">

    private void createNotification() {
        mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext, KillNotificationsService.class),
                mNotificationConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private void removeNotification() {
        mContext.unbindService(mNotificationConnection);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }


    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997800/cancel-notification-on-remove-application-from-multitask-panel
    private ServiceConnection mNotificationConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder binder) {
            ((KillNotificationsService.KillBinder) binder).service.startService(
                    new Intent(mContext, KillNotificationsService.class));

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RecordActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                            .setContentTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setContentText(mContext.getString(R.string.record_notification))
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        }

    };
    //</editor-fold>

}
```